# How do you formally denote a family as a function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

Is there any way to speak of a family by denoting it as a function? In that case, what denotation could we use? And after denoting the said family in the form of a traditional function, say ƒ for now, would I be right if I said that {xᵢ} = ranƒ?

Comment: The statement "let $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of sets in $X$" formally means "let $A$ be a function from $I$ to $X$, and write $A_i$ for $A(i)$". The range of the family can be written as $\{A_i:i\in I\}$. As far as I understand, the symbols $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $\{A_i\}$ are both used to refer to the family itself, i.e. the function $A$. Does that help?

Comment: Most of my query has been cleared, thank you! Of the remaining, will it ever seem conventional to speak of the range and domain of A the same way you would speak of that of a regular function? E.g: let {Ai}(i∈I) be a family of sets in X. Formally, this assigns A as a function that maps indices from a set I to a set X. Can I refer to the range of this family as ranA? If I could, would ranA = {Ai}(i∈I)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should work. Keep in mind, however, that $A$ would be a function from $I$ to the *power set* of $X$, not to $X$.

Comment: @Camelot823: It would be strange to refer to the range of $A$ as $\operatorname{ran}A$, even though it would technically make sense. This is because, in practice, mathematicians don't think of families as functions – rather, they think of them as sets where the elements are ordered in some way (and repeats are allowed). The formal definition of a family as a function is just the way that we "encode" it in set theory, just as how we encode the ordered pair $(a,b)$ as the set $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The word "family" has multiple interpretations. Anyway, a family is some "collection of objects". I think you understand it as an   [indexed family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family) of objects. These objects are elements of some set $X$. An indexed family is formally defined as a function $f : I \to X$. Here $I$ is the *index set*. With $x_i = f(i)$ one often writes $\{x_i\}$ or $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ for indexed families. Personally I do not like this notation because it uses the set braces $\{ \quad \}$ which suggests that an indexed family is itself a set. But this is not true, it contains more information than the image of the index function $f$. If we only know $f(I) = \{ x_i \mid i \in I\}$, we can neither reconstruct the index set $I$ nor the index function $f$. In particular $f$ can have the same value for more than one index, i.e. in an indexed family we can have repetitions.

So yes, you can consider the range $\operatorname{ran}(f)$ of $f$ which is nothing else than $f(I)$ and get $\operatorname{ran}(f) = \{ x_i \} = \{ x_i \mid i \in I\}$.

Note that each set $M$ can be regarded as an indexed family by "self-indexing". Simply take $I = M$ and $f = id : M \to M$.

Using indexed families is unnecessary in many cases, one could work simply with *sets of objects*. This means that often the *range set* $\{ x_i \} $ is completely sufficient for a given purpose.

Comment: much thanks! One query has accomodated my read through your question, though. When a set "self-indexes" itself, the indices are simply the elements of the set, correct?

Comment: @Camelot823 Yes, this is correct.